# How can I use name, ref, defaultValue in select-option like text? - in React Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, meteor, react-bootstrap

I have created a Meteor project with ReactJS.
For the Create/Edit page, I use the same page, in text input, I have the following code:

```
<FormGroup>
<ControlLabel>Province</ControlLabel>
    <input
       type="text"
       className="form-control"
       name="province"
       ref={province => (this.province = province)}
       defaultValue={regs && regs.province}
    />
</FormGroup>
```

To get the same result.
How can I use name, ref, defaultValue in select-option, checkbox, radio,..etc. like text?

```
<FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect"> 
   <ControlLabel>Sex</ControlLabel> 
   <FormControl componentClass="select" name="sex"  ref={sex => (this.sex = sex)} defaultValue={regs && regs.sex}> 
   <option value="male">Male</option> 
   <option value="female">Female</option> 
   </FormControl> 
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: `name` and `ref` work the same with all of them, `defaultValue` works on a `<select />` element, and for checkbox/radio you have `defaultChecked`.

Comment: Hi pawel, thank you very much. defaultValue works well but I found other error that "field sex is undefined". Please see the code that I edit on The topic.

Comment: If `<FormControl />` is a react-bootstrap control I think you should use `inputRef` instead of `ref` https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms-props-form-control

Comment: Hi pawel, it’s working !! This is so great !!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Better create an answer and mark it as correct to close this thread off @MaiSirisak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much to pawel.
I can solve this by changing 
`<FormControl ref=....> to <FormControl inputRef=...>`